# how to get first and last element from array

Tags: php, arrays

guys i am storing dates like these 07/01/2016, 07/02/2016, 07/03/2016, 07/04/2016 in db
and when i fetch these dates from db using mysql_fetch_array() 
the result is the whole array now i want to get only the starting and ending date i.e  07/01/2016 and
07/04/2016...i tried using explode function but explode function breaks a string into an array...and i am unable to find a String To Array function in php...Kindly help me and tell me what should i do...

```
   $leave_dates=$_POST['dates'];
   $check_dates=explode(',', $leave_dates);
    foreach ($check_dates as $date)
{
    # code...
    $count_dates=count($date);
    //THIS GIVES THE COUNT OF DATES E.G 4
    NOW I WANT TO ACCESS THE FIRST AND THE LAST ELEMENT


}
```

Comment: Will this work for first `$check_dates[0]` and  for last `$check_dates[count($check_dates)-1]` and also check by isset first

Comment: First = $check_dates[0]; $last= $check_dates[count($check_dates)-1];

Comment: For first element: `$check_dates[0]` and for last: `$check_dates[(sizeof($check_dates)-1)]`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) and [end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)

```
$firstDate = reset($check_dates);
$lastDate = end($check_dates);
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the potential solution:

```
$leave_dates=$_POST['dates'];
$check_dates=explode(',', $leave_dates);
//To obtain the first element
$first_element=$check_dates[0];
//To obtain the last element
$last_element=$check_dates[count($check_dates)-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php
$row = array('07/01/2016','07/02/2016','07/03/2016','07/04/2016');
$total = count($row);
echo $row[0];
echo "<br>";
echo $row[$total-1];
```

output

```
07/01/2016
07/04/2016
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use array_shift and array_pop

```
$first_element = array_shift($check_dates);
$last_element = array_pop($check_dates);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$firstDate = current($count_dates);
$lastDate = end($count_dates);
```

Comment: can you please expand you answer, and elaborate a bit on the solution?

Comment: current() and end() both are build pointer for the array in php.
you can check the details
http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to work out on Queries.

```
select * from table_name
where id = (select id from tab1 order by col1 asc limit 1) or
id = (select id from tab1 order by col1 desc  limit 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
<?php 

    $check_dates=array('2016-5-11','2016-8-4','2016-4-9');
    $firstDate = current($check_dates);
    $lastDate = end($check_dates);

    print_r($firstDate);
    print_r($lastDate);

?>
```

Output will be :

```
 2016-5-11
 2016-4-9
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you store all the value in an array named $check_dates. You can access the first element of an array with index 0

```
$firstlement=$check_dates['0'];
```

To access the last element of an array, you can use [end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function.

```
$lastement=end($check_dates);
```

Comment: it could be a comment, it's not a full-fledged answer. Please read the best practices: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer